# Uninitialized constant Table with Datamapper and Sinatra

Tags: database, sinatra, datamapper

When I try to access to the data of my table `Task` in irb I've got the error :

> > NameError: Unintialized constant Task

I'm working with Sinatra and I use Datamapper for the database.

```
require "sinatra"
require 'haml'
require 'data_mapper'


get "/" do
  @posts = Post.all
  haml :index
end

DataMapper.setup(:default, ENV['DATABASE_URL'] || "sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/development.db")

class Post
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :title,           String
  property :content,         String
  property :photo,           String
  property :rating,          Serial
end

DataMapper.finalize
```

If you have any idea of the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally the error appears beacause I forgot to `require './main.rb` and to `Post.auto_migrate!` in irb